# transform ggplot axes tick labels

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to rescale gg plot axis labels with my function. For example,

```
sp <- ggplot(cars, aes(x = speed, y = dist)) + geom_point()
sp
```

[image]

How can I rescale the x-axis labels with the given function `exp(exp(x/100))`? Specifically, instead of the current labels 5, 10, 15, 20, and 25, how can I display them as 2.86, 3.02, 3.20, 3.39, 3.61, at the locations of 5, 10, 15, 20, 25?

The values (2.86, 3.02, 3.20, 3.39, 3.61) come from the following transformation:

```
exp(exp(5/100))
exp(exp(10/100))
exp(exp(15/100))
exp(exp(20/100))
exp(exp(25/100))
```

I wish to let R do the calculation and change the displayed values on the axis, instead of us calculating the values and manually change the labels.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use

```
 sp + scale_x_continuous(labels = ~round(exp(exp(./100)),2))
```

[image]

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for! Thanks! Will adopt as the answer in 4 minutes (restricted by the system). Thanks again!